# how to take the integral that contains exponential element

Tags: integration, exponential-function

Can someone help me to find a solution for the following integral?

$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(ax+c)}{(ax+b) ^2} e^{-\frac{x}{b}} dx$

Thank you.

Comment: $$\frac{e^{1/a} \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right) (a b+b-c)+a (b-c)}{a^2 b}$$

Comment: @Raffaele. *"Dont give a child a fish but show him how to fish”* ( Mao Zedong)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Et si le garçon voulait plutôt un espadon?

Comment: @Raffaele. This is a good answer ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the problem more general, consider
$$I=\int \frac{ (\alpha  x+\beta)}{(\gamma  x+\delta )^2}\,e^{- \epsilon x}\,dx$$

Concerning the antiderivative first, let
$\gamma  x+\delta=t$ to make
$$I=\frac{e^{\frac{\delta  \epsilon }{\gamma }} }{\gamma^2} \int\frac{\alpha  t +(\beta  \gamma-\alpha  \delta)}{t^2}  {e^{-\frac{t \epsilon }{\gamma }} }\,dt$$

Now, $t=\frac{\gamma }{\epsilon }y$ to make
$$I=\frac{e^{\frac{\delta  \epsilon }{\gamma }} }{\gamma^3} \int \frac {\alpha  \gamma  y +\epsilon(\beta  \gamma  -\alpha  \delta  )  } {y^2 }\,e^{-y}\,dy$$

Now, two integrals
$$I_1=\int \frac {e^{-y}} y \,dy=\text{Ei}(-y)$$
$$I_2=\int \frac {e^{-y}} {y^2} \,dy=-\text{Ei}(-y)-\frac{e^{-y}}{y}$$

Back to $x$
$$I=\frac{ (\alpha  \delta -\beta  \gamma )}{\gamma ^2 (
   \gamma  x+\delta)}e^{- \epsilon x }+\frac{\alpha  \gamma +\epsilon(\alpha  \delta   -\beta  \gamma  ) }{\gamma ^3 }e^{\frac{\delta  \epsilon }{\gamma }} \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{\epsilon  }{\gamma }(\gamma  x+\delta )\right)$$  Now, for the definite integral, there will be conditions to be fulfilled.

For you specific case, the result would be
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(ax+c)}{(ax+b) ^2} e^{-\frac{x}{b}}\, dx=\frac{a (c-b)-e^{\frac{1}{a}} \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right) (a b+b-c)}{a^2   b}$$ if
$$(\Re(a) \Im(b)\neq \Im(a) \Re(b)\lor \Re(a)\geq 0)\land
   \left(\Re\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\geq 0\lor \frac{b}{a}\notin
   \mathbb{R}\right)\land \Re(b)>0$$

Comment: Thank you @ClaudeLeibovici for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @MinaKayNak. You are welcome ! It is a nice problem.